# Cannot generate subsets of feature class with arcpy (ArcGIS library in Python 2.7)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, arcgis-10.0, python-2.7

I'm having a hard time here on processing GIS data in Python, using library `arcpy`. 
I've been trying to generate independent features from a feature class based on a field of the attribute table which is a unique code representing productive forest units, but I can't get it done. 
I've already done this in other situations, but this time I don't know what I am missing. 
Here is the code and the error I get:

```
# coding utf-8
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
ws = r'D:\Projeto_VANT\SIG\proc_parc.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = ws

talhoes = r'copy_talhoes'

estados = ('SP', 'MG')
florestas = ('PROPRIA', 'PARCERIA')

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(talhoes,
                                          'talhoes_layer',
                                          """ "ESTADO" IN {} AND "FLORESTA" IN {} """.format(estados, florestas),
                                          ws)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features = 'talhoes_layer',
                                            out_path = ws,
                                            out_name = 'talhoes1')
talhoes1 = r'talhoes1'

arcpy.AddField_management(talhoes1, 'CONCAT_T', 'TEXT')
arcpy.CalculateField_management(talhoes1, 'CONCAT_T', """ [ESTADO] & "_" & [CODIGO] & "_" & [TALHAO] """, 'VB')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(talhoes1, ['CONCAT_T', 'AREA']) as tal_cursor:
    for x in tal_cursor:
        print(x[0] + " " + str(x[1])) # This print is just to check if the cursor works and it does!
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(x,
                                          'teste',
                                          """ CONCAT_T = '{}' """.format(str(x[0]))) # Apparently the problem is here!
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('teste',
                                      'Layer{}'.format(x[0]))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/ArcPy_Classes/Scripts/sampling_sig.py", line 32, in <module>
    """ CONCAT_T = '{}' """.format(str(x[0])))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6965, in MakeFeatureLayer
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: @BERA thanks a lot, I knew it was something simple that I was missing. I'm getting started with arcpy recently. Thanks again!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62534287/1446289

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First parameter to MakeFeatureLayer should be a input feature class or layer.

You are passing x which is a tuple of the values of 'CONCAT_T', 'AREA', for example `("somevalue", 1000)`. Maybe it should be `'talhoes_layer'` instead?

If you have ArcMap >= 10.5 (I think), you can use [Split By Attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm):

> Splits an input dataset by unique attributes